What movie is being mocked?
In Scary Movie 2, there is a scene where Cindy is on top of the professor in a Red dress. They hear a noise and Cindy says, "She suspects something". Professor says, "Who" and Cindy replies, "Your wife!"
What movies is this referencing? I believe it was Michelle Phifer and maybe Harrison Ford? I don't recall but it was a movie that took place in a cabin next to lake. 

Harrison Ford and Michelle Pfeiffer were together in What Lies Beneath (2000), which does take place by a lake.

It is indeed parodying a scene from What Lies Beneath. In that movie Claire (Michelle Pfeiffer) is lying over her husband Norman (Harrison Ford) wearing a sexy red dress then this conversation happens:

Claire Spencer: I think she's startin' to suspect something.
Norman: Who?
Claire Spencer: [face morphs into the ghost] Your wife!


If there is an unambiguous reference, it is lost in the noise.  An attractive female student having a fling with her professor has appeared in countless television shows and movies.
I think the moment is amusing because the timing of "She suspects something" is misplaced.  Usually that occurs after the wife has met the student and the professor and student next first meet—not when they are embracing.
